# How to get data from database after event from another screen

Tags: flutter

I came from Android Development, so, I'll try to explain my situation in Android terms in some cases. So, I have the MainScreen, which uses Scaffold and has FAB. The body of this screen is another widget (as Fragment in Android). When I click on the FAB (which is on MainScreen), bottom modal is opened. By this model, I can add data to the database. But I also want to add new data to my widget (fragment) at the same time. And I don't know in which method of lifecycle I should do call to DB. In android such method is `onResume`, but I didn't find it's analogue in Flutter.

I'll appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

**UPD**

There's my screen:

[image]

Bottom navigation and FAB is on the MainScreen. ListView is on the widget, which is body of MainScreen's Scaffold. Another my step is clicking on FAB. This click opens bottom modal

[image]

When I click save on the modal, data is saved to DB and modal close. And after this closing I want to see new database entry, which I just added from the modal. Now I can see new notes only after closing and then opening screen again. Here's my code:

```
class NotesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotesScreenState createState() => _NotesScreenState();
}

class _NotesScreenState extends State<NotesScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  List<Note> _notes = new List<Note>();


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Fimber.i("Init");
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    NotesDataManager().getNotes().then((value) {
      _notes = value;
      setState(() {
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state){
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        NotesDataManager().getNotes().then((value){
          _notes = value;
          setState(() {
          });
        });
        Fimber.i("Resumed");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        Fimber.i("Inactive");

        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        Fimber.i("Paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
        Fimber.i("Suspending");
        break;
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(AppColors.layoutBackgroundColor),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _notes.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return NotesListItemWidget(note: _notes[index]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I added `WidgetsBindingObserver`, but it didn't help

Comment: why do you need onResume on a running application?

Comment: @Marc updated the question

Comment: WidgetBindingObserver is for something completely different. As i stated you dont need it for your case. The answer to your question is pretty complicated cause it involves a lot of steps. I will check on that later hopefully.

Comment: Are you using any state management?

Comment: @Marat, probably no

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use state management in your app. The easiest one is Provider. Your model should extend `ChangeNotifier` and whenever you add a new instance of model the app will be notified: `notifyListener`. In `build` you will implement `ChangeNotifierProvider`. Here is some tutorials:

[Provider example 1](https://dev.to/shakib609/create-a-todos-app-with-flutter-and-provider-jdh)

[Provider example 2](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-architecture-my-provider-implementation-guide/)

Or you can just search for `Provider`